# How i can loop over this string and find count of number greater than 3.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I Want to Loop over string and find count which for those which are greater than 3.0

```
rainfall_mi = "1.65, 1.46, 2.05, 3.03, 3.35, 3.46, 2.83, 3.23, 3.5, 2.52, 2.8, 1.85"
```

Comment: what did you try to do? do you know how to `split()` a string? do you know how to make a `float()` from a single string representing a float number? `'25.34'`->`25.34` do you know about [loops](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
len([float(i) for i in rainfall_mi.split(',') if float(i)> 3.0])
```